# Supervisor doesn't start on startup on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, supervisord, init.d

I installed Supervisor on Ubuntu 16.04 with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

Supervisor 3.2.0-2 successfully installed and works if I run it with the command:

```
sudo service supervisor start
```

But after reboot it doesn't start automatically.
There is an init script in the init.d directory and it runs supervisor as well:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/supervisor start
```

I'd tried to add this init script to startup:

```
sudo update-rc.d supervisor defaults
```

After that I checked the `/etc/rc*.d` directories and there are symlinks like:

```
/etc/rc0.d/@K02supervisor
/etc/rc1.d/@K02supervisor
/etc/rc2.d/@S01supervisor
/etc/rc3.d/@S01supervisor
/etc/rc4.d/@S01supervisor
/etc/rc5.d/@S01supervisor
/etc/rc6.d/@K02supervisor
```

But supervisor doesn't start at startup.
How can I start it every time after server reboot?

Comment: Try adding some debug outputs to the startup script, it might be failing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to execute the command for starting a service at system up. For systemd on Ubuntu 16.04, this would be:

```
sudo systemctl enable supervisor
```

Also your command to start the service should be updated to:

```
sudo systemctl start supervisor
```

Comment: That does not helps, unfortunately.